# How do I send pipes and regex from Vim to bash shell?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sorting, vim

I would like to know how to pass pipes from vim to bash.... p.e.

This command works in my bash shell:

```
$ sort -k2n -t'|' /cygdrive/d/test55.txt
```

If I open the text file in Vim and apply the same command

```
:%!sort -k2n -t'|'
```

it gives an error:
''' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Same problem with regex.
Isn't it possible to pass regex from vim to bash?
p.e.

```
:%!sort -k3 -t'\a\{3,}'
```

(sort after the 3rd time a word is longer then 3 characters)

or

```
:%!sort -k3 -t'[,;]'
```

(sort after the 3rd time a ',' or ';' is found)

1) How can I pass pipes to bash?
2) How can I send regex to bash?

Comment: escape the special characters - `|`, `\ `, `[` with extra `\ `.

Comment: Works for me (v7.3.547).

Comment: @anishsane I've already tried to escape them but still same error. Escaping the '\' works fine. The comma, '-' and '[' work also without escaping.

Comment: I think You mistyped something! It works for me. `Sort` uses a single character as field separator, otherwise it reports `sort: multi-character tab `,;'` error.

Comment: @TrueY The same command works with comma inside. Is it possible that it has something to do with cygwin? I'am working on a windows machine with cygwin installed.

Comment: @Remonn: I tested it with sort 8.15-1 under `cygwin`.

Comment: @TrueY, strange... which Vim version do you use?

Comment: @Remonn: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun  9 2013 08:25:56); Included patches: 1-1110, 1112-1152`

Comment: @TrueY@Ansgar Wiechers, you both have beta vim versions installed (I suppose). I still use the default vim for windows version 7.3.46 compiled oct.27 2010. Can it be a vim bug?

Comment: @Remonn: I use the default cygwin distribution. Maybe it is a little bit out of date. I'm going to update if I can stop cygwin on my PC and check the newest version.

Comment: @Remonn: I updated my cygwin right now from `ftp://mirrors.kernel.org`. 7.3 is the latest `vim` in this package.

Comment: @TrueY, I updated it last week. BTW I use the external vim version for windows, not the cygwin vi.

Comment: I still have no idea why it doesn't work!

Comment: I'm using the version shipped with Debian Wheezy. That's hardly a beta. If you're using Vim on Windows you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, no problem :) I think it has something to do with my cygwin version. All variables which needs escapes gives an error (except escaping the '\')

Comment: I checked many times: I typed nothing wrong (I typed what I wrote in my question). I've read the whole day manuals. Can't find out why. I reinstalled cygwin, no difference. I used the original _vimrc, no difference. Still don't know whats happening. Nobody has an idea?